# One to one correspondence between sets of base 2 and base 4 sequences

Tags: elementary-set-theory

We need to find a one to correspondence (injection) between the set of all binary sequences and the set of all quaternary $\{0,1,2,3\}$ sequences.

This is what I came up with:

$B=$ binary sequence

$Q=$ quaternary sequence

$\phi : Q \to B = [f(1\sigma_1\sigma_2\sigma_3...)] $

$f=$ "Decimal to binary conversion"

For example, the sequence: $001321$ will become $1001321$ then $f$ will covert it from decimal to binary resulting in: $11110100011101101001$ (I used an [online converter](http://www.mathsisfun.com/binary-decimal-hexadecimal-converter.html) to get this value).

$\phi^{-1}: B \to Q $ Can basically be the same only to remove the one after conversion.

Is this ok ? Is there a better way ?

Thanks.

Comment: Finite sequences or infinite sequences? As to the conversion, why introduce decimals? Direct conversion from binary to base $4$ is easy (or conversely) is easy. If finite sequences, it is useful to use the first "digit" to indicate whether the number of entries is even or odd.

Comment: Your idea is not correct.  There is no quaternary sequence that maps to the binary sequence `111`, because that is the binary representation of the number 7, and there is no quaternary sequence that has the decimal value 7.  So in particular $\phi^{-1}(\mathtt{111})$ is undefined.

Comment: @AndréNicolas it is not stated so I guess infinite.

Comment: The default assumption depends on the course. It should be clarified. Infinite is somewhat simpler. The most complicated (but not really bad) is if both finite and infinite are allowed.

Comment: Well in previous assignments when I answered the questions as if the sets were finite, it turned out it was wrong and the explanation was that it wasn't necessarily finite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you talk about sequences it appears that leading zeros are not a problem.  The naive thing is to take the quaternary sequence and change each character to two binary characters in the obvious way:  $0 \to 00, 1 \to 01, 2 \to 10, 3 \to 11$.  This is a fine bijection between the quaternary sequences and the even-length binary sequences.  If the sequences are infinite, you are done.

For doing all finite length strings we can do the following:  Sort all the finite binary and quaternary strings in order, first by length, then by magnitude in the respective base.  So the binary strings start out $0,1,00,01,10,11,000,001,\dots$.  If we assign the number $0$ to the first, we can find the length of the string $n$ by $L(n)=1+\lfloor \log_2(n)\rfloor$.  The string itself will be the binary representation of $n-2^{L(n)}$, padded in front with zeros to  length $L(n)$.  This is a bijection between the naturals (including $0$) and the binary strings.

We can define the obvious matching bijection between the naturals and the quaternary strings.  It is a little harder to describe because the sum of the powers of $4$ doesn't come out so nicely.  Define $M(p)$ as the position of the first string of $p$ digits.  We have $M(1)=0, M(2)=5, M(p)=\sum_{i=0}^{p-1}4^i=\frac {4^p-1}3$ so the length of string $n$ is $LL(n)=\lfloor \log_4 (3n+1) \rfloor$ except that $LL(0)=1$ so $n$ corresponds to the string made by representing $n-M(LL(n))$ in base $4$ and zero padding to length $LL(n)$

Comment: I thought about that, but what happens when you have the binary sequence: "000" ? And how can you go back without any duality ? For example: $1311 \to 01110101$ now going back you have to define a function that treats the values in packs of 2.

Comment: That was my point about even length sequences.  When I saw your comment about infinite sequences that solved the problem-you never run out of bits.  Yes, going back you just split the bits into pairs and take the pair to a single quaternary digit.  As your function is on sequences, not on bits, that is not a problem.